# PowerShell run Scheduled Task on another server

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have serverA that contains all my powershell scripts.

I have serverB that has Windows Scheduled tasks.

How do I call and execute a Scheduled Task on serverB from serverA?

I have tried the below from serverA

```
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "LoadJobs" -ComputerName serverB
```

But I keep receiving the error:

```
Start-ScheduledTask : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ComputerName'.
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverB -ScriptBlock {schtasks /run /tn "LoadJobs"}
```

I cannot take the credit - got the answer from here:

https://powershell.org/forums/topic/run-deligated-scheduled-task-on-remote-server-via-ps-without-admin-rghts/

Comment: schtasks has a computername parameter. `schtasks /run /s \\$cn /TN $taskname`